# running a console application with arguments using exec()

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I am able to call the following exe using windows command line, but using the exec() function, it doesn't work.

I have to pass a directory as an argument to that exe file.

UPDATE:

```
$command = '""C:\\Users\\cArn\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\word_to_pdf\\word_to_pdf\\bin\\Debug\\word_to_pdf.exe" "C:\\wamp\\www\\zabjournal\\files\\journals\\1\\articles""';
exec($command);
```

Still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: in the command line I think you would quote the path to your exe as it has spaces in it..

Comment: and also change `"\"` to `"\\"`

Comment: The webpage does take some time to load the page, I'm assuming that I got the application to run, but there is no output from the application (it doesnt output pdf files) but it does using cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote `'` instead

```
$command = 'C:\Users\cArn\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\word_to_pdf\word_to_pdf\bin\Debug\word_to_pdf.exe C:\wamp\www\zabjournal\files\journals\1\articles';
exec($command);
```

Thanks

:)

Answer (score 0):

try

`passthru($command)` instead off `exec()`